# Curvature of electrostatic potential is zero

Tags: electrostatics, mathematical-physics, potential, curvature

Could you please expound upon this claim? I found such claim on Zangwill's *Classical Electrodynamics,* which states that constraint coming from Laplacian equation implies

1. electrostatic potential has zero curvature, and
2. is not bounded in at least one direction.

What kind of curvature are we talking about here? 
Please explain both points for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The electric potential $\phi:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ is the solution to [Laplace's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_equation) and therefore a [harmonic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function). Harmonic functions enjoy several nice properties, some of them listed on the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function) page.

Concerning OP's second point, let us mention that there is a theorem similar to [Liouville's theorem from complex analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28complex_analysis%29) that a bounded harmonic function defined on the whole $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a constant function .

Concerning OP's first point, Zangwill is looking at the [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_of_a_function)

$$ {\rm graph}(\phi)~=~ \{({\bf r}, \phi({\bf r}))~\in~ \mathbb{R}^4\mid {\bf r}\in\mathbb{R}^3 \} ~\subset~ \mathbb{R}^4 .$$

The graph of $\phi$ is a 3-dimensional submanifold with possible curvature embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$. The metric on the graph is induced from the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: And this induced metric happens to be a flat metric is what he is saying?

Comment: The induced metric is not necessarily flat, but the [mean curvature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_curvature) is zero at stationary points.

Comment: @Qmechanic I doubt your second comment is right. The mean curvature, $H$, for the graph of any function $\phi:U\subset\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$ satisfies $nH=\text{div}\left(\frac{\nabla\phi}{\sqrt{1+|\nabla\phi|^2}}\right)=\frac{\Delta \phi}{\sqrt{1+|\nabla\phi|^2}}-\frac{D^2\phi[\nabla\phi,\nabla\phi]}{(1+|\nabla\phi|^2)^{3/2}}$. FOr harmonic functions, the first term vanishes, but the second need not (if we're at a critical point, then it will of course (that critical point necessarily being a saddle of course))

Comment: @peek-a-boo: Thanks. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

There are several definitions of the term *curvature* in mathematics, but I think the simplest explanation of the first point is in regards to the second derivative of a function.  The Laplacian is really just the second derivative of the electric potential equal to zero.  Think of a straight line.  Such an object has a finite first derivative but zero second derivative.  In contrast, a parabola will have finite first and second derivatives, and thus a finite curvature.

I think this is consistent with @Qmechanic's post, but he/she is much more adept at math than I so I will let them clarify.

**Side Note:**  The Poisson equation for an electrostatic potential, for comparison, can have curvature under the definition I used.

Comment: The issue here is cases like $V(x,y) = x^2 - y^2$. The point $(x,y) = (0,0)$ is a saddle point, and the Gaussian curvature there is negative. However, the mean curvature, which is roughly what the Laplacian corresponds to, at this point is zero.