# How does Laplace's equation $\nabla^2U = 0$ indicate saddle points?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, potential, vector-fields, stability

When I learned about saddle points I had this expression 'rt-(s^2)', where r=Dx, t=Dy, s=Dxy=Dyx. And the intuition behind why it is so was also clear.

In an electric/magnetic field, in [Earnshaw' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earnshaw%27s_theorem) stable equilibrium can't exist - in some direction it has to be unstable (that's why saddle points I guess). But how does $\nabla^2U = 0$ indicate so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$C^2$-solutions to [Laplace's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_equation) are by definition [harmonic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function), which in turn satisfy a [strong maximum principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_principle): The maximum/minimum in the interior is only possible for constant functions. In other words: any [stationary/critical point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_point) for a non-constant function is a [saddle point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point).

See also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136940/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/377522/2451) related Phys.SE posts.