# How do I visualize the Laplacian equation?

Tags: electromagnetism, potential

The question arose when looking at the Laplacian of a potential in E&M and I'm not sure I can explain what it means if I were asked this on a quiz. I think it detects whether the potential function is increasing or decreasing, but I am not confident saying that. If someone can enlighten me more on the subject I would be grateful.

Comment: curvature, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136940/curvature-of-electrostatic-potential-is-zero